# Creating a fully isolated python venv for pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, hadoop-yarn, python-venv

I deploy pyspark applications on a `yarn` cluster with the python `venv` on a mount accessible from all nodes. The problem I am having is that the python installation on the nodes is inconsistent, where some nodes have a required module installed (that is part of the python build) and others don't, which causes frequent crashes. I noticed that when creating a venv with `python -m venv` it doesn't copy the python installation, but rather creates a `symlink` to it.

It proved tedious to communicate with the team responsible for the cluster about this, so I would like to instead create a fully isolated python installation on the mount as a solution to this case and future problems to come. I did not find any way to do this with the `venv` module. I thought instead to migrate the project environment to a conda environment, which to my understanding installs a separate python installation. However, I would ideally want to do this with `venv` as I'd rather not introduce another technology into my stack and do the migration. However, I would like to know if there are other simple/recommended solutions to this problem.

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> the python installation on the nodes is inconsistent, where some nodes have a required module installed and others don't

Ideally, you wouldn't use Spark to solve that problem. Use tools like Ansible or Puppet to deploy/manage state across a cluster of servers, as well as a consistent Python installation version. I.e. don't pack Python 3.10 venv, then try to run on the cluster where it only has Python 3.6 ...

Otherwise, the [PySpark documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/user_guide/python_packaging.html#using-virtualenv) covers exactly what you need.

Use `venv-pack`

> ```
> python -m venv pyspark_venv
> source pyspark_venv/bin/activate
> pip install venv-pack
> pip install pyarrow pandas  # project dependencies
> venv-pack -o pyspark_venv.tar.gz
> ```

> You can directly pass/unpack the archive file and enable the environment on executors by leveraging the `--archives` option or `spark.archives` configuration (`spark.yarn.dist.archives` in YARN).

> For `spark-submit`, you can use it by running the command as follows. Also, notice that `PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON` has to be unset in Kubernetes or YARN cluster modes.

> ```
> export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=python # Do not set in cluster modes.
> export PYSPARK_PYTHON=./environment/bin/python
> spark-submit --archives pyspark_venv.tar.gz#environment app.py
> ```

Comment: This is not a pip package, it's part of the python build, I need to package the whole python installation. From [the docs](https://jcristharif.com/venv-pack/index.html): "Python is not packaged with the environment, but rather symlinked in the environment. This is useful for deployment situations where Python is already installed on the machine, but the required library dependencies may not be."

Comment: As answered, Spark is not responsible for managing OS dependencies. Most Linux distributions already have Python, and `venv` itself requires Python to be installed anyway. Environments are not replacements for the Python interpreters, and you only can package the environment to distribute via Spark. Everything else needs managed by the OS package manager